# Is it possible to show page without scroll bar though page length is higher then single page?

Tags: html, css

When page length is more then single page, scorll bar can be seen.

Is it possible to remove it for higher page size also? Page should be moved up down by `pageup` `pagedown` or `arrow` keys

Comment: How would a user scroll the page on a device with no keyboard?

Comment: The scrollbar tells the user there's more content to see. Why would you want to hide it?

Comment: @MicahHenning: you point is correct. But looking at my page I found that preview of my page was changing in presence of scrollbar. Without SB it has better look. So just wanted to try it out

Comment: Can you provide a link to your page, or create a jsFiddle to illustrate your dilemma?  Maybe there's another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css overflow property

```
body{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

for vertical and horizontal scroll.

```
body{
  overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

for vertical scroll only.

Comment: This actually doesn't solve the problem because you won't be able to scroll the page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317364/remove-scrollbar-but-not-scrolling-functionality

Comment: But those are just hacks. Either you have to use browser-specific CSS properties to hide the scrollbars or give them transparent backgrounds colors, or you have to "push it out of view" using a wrapper element.