# vertical scroll off but scrolling allowed

Tags: html, css

I want that the scollbar is hidden but you can still scroll. 
if I now do:

```
body{
  overflow-y:hidden
}
```

the vertical scroll is hidden but you can't scroll.
my question: is there a way to hide the scrollbar but you can still scroll?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326570/how-can-i-disable-a-browser-or-element-scrollbar-but-still-allow-scrolling-with

Comment: thanks for your anwser. I will take a look at doing it with Jquery

Comment: The code you have given works just fine, by allowing scroll with no visible scroll bar vertically..!

Comment: Here, it was answered without JQuery, using only CSS:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317364/remove-scrollbar-but-not-scrolling-functionality

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try to add padding-right:20px; and overflow-x:hidden; to the overflowing element, hiding the scrollbar. Not sure if it works on body though.