# Removing scrollbars but leave scrolling functionality

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know that there are almost the same questions related to scrollbars with some good answers, unfortunately that did not work for me. I want to hide scrollbars leaving scrolling functionality. Here is what I have:

```html
<div class="sidebar">
     <div id="status"> </div>
 <..li items etc >  
    </div><!-- END SIDEBAR -->
```

And my CSS,

```html
.sidebar {
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 90%;
}
.sidebar .#status {
 overflow:scroll;
}
```

My status id div is empty initially, and I have some list items (links) after it, what I am doing is that my status id div is being filled with li elements via ajax, since there are many of them i need scrollbar functionality, but since it is my sidebar positioned at the left side I do not want scrollbars to appear.
Note: Making parent div overflow:hiddent and child one to scroll doesn't help.

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317364/remove-scrollbar-but-not-scrolling-functionality)

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16671476/2219158

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
overflow: hidden
```

on the parent, and then set

```
overflow-y: scroll
```

on the container. An example for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/DGmUK/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a outer-bow that crops the scrollbars off.

```
.outer{
width:200px;
height:200px;
overflow:hidden;
}
.scrollbox{
width:260px;
height:200px;
overflow:scroll;
}
.inner{
width:190px;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/johanthuresson/bj6wb0xo/1/